# Inserting multiple rows into a table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I’m having fun with EF and have come unstuck.

Originally I used the following bit of code using standard linq that essentially enters some data into a table.

```
ManagePreferencesDataContext manpref = new ManagePreferencesDataContext();

                tblManagePreference prefMemberID = new tblManagePreference();
                {
                    prefMemberID.Username = CreateUserWizard1.UserName;
                    prefMemberID.MemberID = tbxMemberID.Text.ToString();
                    prefMemberID.LocationID = tbxLocationID.Text.ToString();
                    prefMemberID.Preference = "MemberID";
                }

                tblManagePreference prefLocationID = new tblManagePreference();
                {
                    prefLocationID.Username = CreateUserWizard1.UserName;
                    prefLocationID.MemberID = tbxMemberID.Text.ToString();
                    prefLocationID.LocationID = tbxLocationID.Text.ToString();
                    prefLocationID.Preference = "LocationID";
                }


                List<tblManagePreference> ie = new List<tblManagePreference>();
                ie.Add(prefMemberID);
                ie.Add(prefLocationID);

                manpref.tblManagePreferences.InsertAllOnSubmit(ie);
                manpref.SubmitChanges();
```

Now, I’ve tried to replicate the same, or similar code using the EF and have totally come unstuck.

I tried to use the list and .AddTotblManagePreferences but receive a “Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the tblManagePreferences EntitySet.  Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet property instead.

I’ve had a look at ObjectSet  briefly but I’m not really sure how to amend the code.

```
    VDSORDAL.PDC_VDSOREntities manpref = new PDC_VDSOREntities();
        tblUserPreference prefMemberID = new tblUserPreference();

        {
            prefMemberID.Username = CreateUserWizard1.UserName;
            prefMemberID.MemberID = tbxMemberID.Text.ToString();
            prefMemberID.LocationID = tbxLocationID.Text.ToString();
            prefMemberID.ColumnName = "MemberID";


        }

        tblUserPreference prefLocationID = new tblUserPreference();
        {
            prefLocationID.Username = CreateUserWizard1.UserName;
            prefLocationID.MemberID = tbxMemberID.Text.ToString();
            prefLocationID.LocationID = tbxLocationID.Text.ToString();
            prefLocationID.ColumnName = "LocationID";
        }

    List<tblUserPreference> ie = new List<tblUserPreference>();
        ie.Add(prefMemberID);
        ie.Add(prefLocationID);


        manpref.AddObject(PDC_VDSOREntities,ie);
        manpref.SaveChanges();
```

If anyone has used something along these lines before or could point me in the right direction, I’d be most grateful.

Although enthusiastic, I can't help but feeling thick as pig poo at the moment.

Comment: Yes there is a property called tblUserPreferences

(Sorry - I tried adding it to our comment thread but I wasn't allowed : S )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I presume you have recreated your model in the Entity Framework designer? This should have created a class deriving from ObjectContext specific to your model. By convention, this ends in "Entities".

Have a look at your `ManagePreferencesEntities` instance - or whatever yours is called. It should have a property on it corresponding to the table for your entities, `tblManagePreferences` perhaps. This is the `ObjectSet` instance for that specific table, and it has an `AddObject` method that you can use to add entities into that table.

Try this instead of the last 5 or so lines of code:

```
manpref.tblUserPreferences.AddObject(prefMemberId);
manpref.tblUserPreferences.AddObject(prefLocationId);
manpref.SaveChanges();
```

By default ObjectSet doesn't support adding lists of things, but it's easy to create your own extension method:

```
public static class ObjectSetExtensions
{
     public static void AddObjects<T>(this ObjectSet<T> objectSet, IEnumerable<T> objects)
     {
         foreach (var item in objects)
         {
            objectSet.AddObject(item);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hello Samuel, thanks for looking at this for me.

I have attempted the following (see edit above) but without success. Apologies for being thick - very new to all of this and qute out of my depth!

Comment: Can you confirm that there is a property called tblUserPreferences on PDC_VDSOREntities?

Comment: Brilliant stuff - thank you very much Sam. very useful indeed. I owe you a pint.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
manPref.tblManagePreference.Add(prefMemberID);
manPref.tblManagePreference.Add(prefLocationID);
manPref.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using entity framework 5 now.
When you use:

```
objectcontext.Add(yourobject1);
objectcontext.Add(yourobject2);
objectcontext.SaveChanges();
```

then only last of your objects will be inserted into database.

But if you will use:

```
objectcontext.Entry(yourobject1).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
objectcontext.Entry(yourobject2).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
objectcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Then all of your objects will be added.