# Entity framework insert multiple rows from dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Have two entities, Customer and Contacts.

I'm saving changes with `dbContext.SaveChanges();`

```
- If I enter one row into contactDataGridView (one contact)
    * data is saved to db

- If I enter multiple rows into contactDataGridView (many contacts)
    * ERROR : Validation failed for one or more entities. 
              See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Quote from SO question [Inserting multiple rows into a table using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227525/inserting-multiple-rows-into-a-table-using-entity-framework)

> > By default ObjectSet doesn't support adding lists of things, but it's easy to create your own extension method:

```
public static class ObjectSetExtensions
{
     public static void AddObjects<T>(this ObjectSet<T> objectSet, IEnumerable<T> objects)
     {
        foreach (var item in objects)
        {
            objectSet.AddObject(item);
        }
     }
 }
```

Is that answer to my problem ? Do I need to create list as the answer says?

If yes, how to do that?

Comment: Post some code please, as described the question is too broad/unclear.

Comment: I don't have any insert/update code. I use auto generated from entity framework. Please tell me what code do I need to put here.